# jQuery: Is :first faster than .className:first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, debugging, frontend

Reguarding jQuery, I've read somewhere that slecting by class can be significantly slower than selecting by ID.

When using the :first selector, does jQuery find all instances and only return the first  element? Or does the parser stop once the first element is found?

Comment: The `:first` pseudo-class is a qualifier applied along with any other part of the selector. If an element has class "className", it still won't be selected if it's not the first child node of its parent. In other words, ".className:first" does not mean, "the first child with class 'className'" - it means, "elements with class 'className' **and** which are the first children of their parents."

Comment: I've never had issues with selectors running slow enough that they were worth benchmarking. These sorts of questions, while interesting in the academic sense, are rarely useful in practice.

Comment: Run some jsPerf tests to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question but:

Using `.first()` is about ten times faster than using `:first`. Tested using Firefox

> 100,000 iterations:
>
> 55,870ms using :first
>
> 5,858ms using .first()

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    var i, time = +new Date;
    for ( i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) {
        $ ( 'div:first' );
    }
    console.log ( (+new Date) - time );

    time = +new Date;
    for ( i = 0; i < 100000; ++i ) {
        $ ( 'div' ).first ( );
    }
    console.log ( (+new Date) - time );
});
```

As the comments have suggested, try using [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: Firefox 3.6???  Wow. I suspect that one of the dozen or so newer releases of Firefox would show significantly different results.